# JQuery Show Hide div from div collection on button click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am building one UI which enable users to enter their information i.e. firstname, lastname, contact number. At a time, only 5 person entries are possible.
Here is the pre-set HTML :

```
<div class="row rootPerson">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- root person always stays there --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row person2" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="removeperson2">Remove person</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row person3" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="removeperson3">Remove person</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row person4" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="removeperson4">Remove person</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- server control --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row btnAddMorePerson">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- button --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row btnForm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%-- button --%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div with class name [rootPerson] will always stay. Clicking on [addMoreBtn] will show up following div with the class name starts with [person*].this div can be hid again by clicking on div with the class name starts with [removePerson*].

I want to show/hide div having classname starts with [person*], can be more than i defined here.

if person2 is visible, the follwing div person3 will be show up on addMore button click. if person2 was removed,addMore will show up person2.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem? Post some jQuery code please... Also, if you're styling all those divs as a table...why not use the html table element?

Comment: @A.Wolff i am out of logic as i am jquery beginner. logic will work if i can find it here. Thanks.

Comment: @LaveLoos div instead html is just because it's a practice as i am also using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working on a similar functionality in javascript for my own project.
You can add the HTML by pressing on a button via javascript to the page.

I made you a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vjGdw/

I have also added a remove button, that is mapped to the javascript function `RemovePerson()`.

If you are interested how exactly I have implemented this in my project, you find it here:
http://carbocount.wikidot.com/project:products:visualization

Feel free to ask if you have more questions

Comment: i tried your script adding stuffed html dynamically. but getting parser error. i think the solution is not right. i guess i should build interface through scripting like your provided, but also provide html dynamically, not pre-defined as at the end i need values which i think, i'll get it through jquery ajax call or REST API. Thanks

Comment: What browser were you using? Works fine for me in chrome

Comment: your script worked perfectly, i checked fiddle. i was getting parser error when i put my html in that, in by visual studio.